# How to get all TreeViewItems between two items

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a WPF TreeView that visualizes a simple hierarchical structure like the following:

```
> item1
     item1_1
   > item1_2
        item1_2_1
  item2
  item3
```

Here, each item can have any number of descendants. Given an arbitrary pair of items (for example `item1_1` and `item3`) how do I obtain all the items in between (i.e. `item1_2`, `item1_2_1` and `item3`)?

Comment: Won't it be easier to get these items from itemssource rather then from treeview itself?

Answer (score 0):

Not optimized but working

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="800" FontSize="25">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
            <TreeViewItem Header="A">
                <TreeViewItem Header="AA">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="AAA"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="AAB"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="AB"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="B">
                <TreeViewItem Header="BA"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="BB">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="BBA"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="BBB"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Name="txt1"/>
            <TextBlock Name="txt2"/>
            <ListBox Name="lst" ></ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private object itm1;
    private object itm2;

    private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (itm1 == null || (itm1 != null && itm2 != null))
        {
            itm1 = e.NewValue;
            itm2 = null;
            txt1.Text = itm1.ToString();
            txt2.Text = "";

            return;
        }

        itm2 = e.NewValue;
        txt2.Text = itm2.ToString();

        var tree = sender as ItemsControl;
        firstFound = false;
        secondFound = false;
        between = new List<object>();

        checkCollection(tree);

        lst.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var itm in between)
        {
            lst.Items.Add(itm.ToString());
        }

    }

    bool firstFound = false;
    bool secondFound = false;
    List<object> between = new List<object>();
    private void checkCollection(object ctrl)
    {
        if (secondFound)
            return;

        if (!firstFound && (ctrl == itm1 || ctrl == itm2))
        {
            firstFound = true;
        }
        else if (firstFound && (ctrl == itm1 || ctrl == itm2))
        {
            secondFound = true;
            return;
        }

        if (firstFound)
        {
            between.Add(ctrl);
        }

        var itmsCtrl = ctrl as ItemsControl;
        foreach (var itm in itmsCtrl.Items)
        {
            checkCollection(itm);
        }
    }
}
```